# NSOutlineView loses children's order in a flash the first time expanding their parent item

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nsoutlineview

I have an `NSOutlineView` (source list style) bound to a `NSTreeController` whose Content Array is bound to an array of custom objects. The `selectionIndexPaths`, `sortDescriptors` and `arrangedObjects` are also all bound.

When (1)there are 7 or more Child items under a Parent item, (2)after the app has started with the Parent collapsed, and (3)after the Parent is expanded for the first time, there will be a very brief "flash" moment that the children's order is REVERSED. It's SO QUICK that I had to screen record it to see what's going on.

It seems this doesn't happen every time, but I don't quite bebieve my "vision system"(eye, brain etc.) now.

I made a very simple example with 100 items in the Source List, but it didn't reproduce the problem. The real app is a work project so I can't share the real code.

I did found a solution to eliminate the flash: call `treeController`'s `rearrangeObjects()` in `outlineViewItemDidExpand(_ notification: Notification)`. But this introduces another problem: the sidebar's expanding animation will be faster than usual.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you return the child items in an incorrect order in the example?

Comment: Yes, it is an already sorted array. I print() it during the course every thing seems fine. The problem is, when it is expanded, the order is correct, but just in a flash, the children are all reversed, then the order is correct again. It's in the middle there's something wierd. But I still can't address the cause of the isssue.